# No backupset selected to restore

Tags: sql-server, restore, ssms

I have 2 cloud SQL Servers, one in Azure, one in AWS (I don't think the cloud platforms matter here but including them just to be thorough). I'm unable to restore a database from the Azure server to the AWS one using the SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) tools Restore database dialog.

The dialog just shows "No backupset selected to restore". I am able to restore the database scripting out the T-SQL command and running it in a query window.

### Server information

#### Azure

SSMS Tools version: 17.7 (14.0.17254.0)

SQL Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU7-GDR) (KB4057119) -13.0.4466.4 (X64)   Dec 22 2017 11:25:00   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

#### AWS

SSMS Tools version: 17.9 (14.0.17285.0)

SQL Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU13) (KB4466404) - 14.0.3048.4 (X64)   Nov 30 2018 12:57:58   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 10.0  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

### Things I've tried

1. Using the "Restore database" dialog - No backupset selected to restore
2. Backing up an existing database on the AWS server to the same folder as my azure backup file and restoring it through the dialog - works fine
3. Restoring the Azure backup from T-SQL - works fine
4. Adding permissions for the NT Service\MSSQLSERVER user to the folder where the backup is - No backupset selected to restore
5. Running SSMS as admin - No backupset selected to restore
6. Making sure my SQL login has correct permissions, sysadmin and dbcreator - No backupset selected to restore

Those were all of the answers specified in [“No backupset selected to be restored” SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119891/no-backupset-selected-to-be-restored-sql-server-2012), which didn't work for me.

The only difference is where the backup was taken from. When the backup is created from the same server the "No backupset selected" error goes away. When I select the backup taken from the other server the error doesn't go away, no matter what options are selected.

Here is the T-SQL I ran:

```
RESTORE DATABASE TC_SGData_82019
FROM DISK='D:\SQL\Backup\TestCases\TC_SGData_82019.bak'
WITH MOVE 'TC_SGData_82019' TO 'D:\SQL\Data\SGData_82019.mdf',
    MOVE 'TC_SGData_82019_log' TO 'D:\SQL\Logs\SGData_82019_log.ldf'
```

Here are the messages:

```
Processed 442104 pages for database 'TC_SGData_82019', file 'TC_SGData_82019' on file 1.
Processed 4 pages for database 'TC_SGData_82019', file 'TC_SGData_82019_log' on file 1.
Converting database 'TC_SGData_82019' from version 852 to the current version 869.
Database 'TC_SGData_82019' running the upgrade step from version 852 to version 853.
Database 'TC_SGData_82019' running the upgrade step from version 853 to version 854.
Database 'TC_SGData_82019' running the upgrade step from version 854 to version 855.
Database 'TC_SGData_82019' running the upgrade step from version 855 to version 856.
Database 'TC_SGData_82019' running the upgrade step from version 856 to version 857.
Database 'TC_SGData_82019' running the upgrade step from version 857 to version 858.
Database 'TC_SGData_82019' running the upgrade step from version 858 to version 859.
Database 'TC_SGData_82019' running the upgrade step from version 859 to version 860.
Database 'TC_SGData_82019' running the upgrade step from version 860 to version 861.
Database 'TC_SGData_82019' running the upgrade step from version 861 to version 862.
Database 'TC_SGData_82019' running the upgrade step from version 862 to version 863.
Database 'TC_SGData_82019' running the upgrade step from version 863 to version 864.
Database 'TC_SGData_82019' running the upgrade step from version 864 to version 865.
Database 'TC_SGData_82019' running the upgrade step from version 865 to version 866.
Database 'TC_SGData_82019' running the upgrade step from version 866 to version 867.
Database 'TC_SGData_82019' running the upgrade step from version 867 to version 868.
Database 'TC_SGData_82019' running the upgrade step from version 868 to version 869.
RESTORE DATABASE ... FILE=<name> successfully processed 442108 pages in 86.013 seconds (40.156 MB/sec).
```

I updated to the latest SSMS version 18.2 (15.0.18142.0) with the same results. Here's a screentshot of the restore dialog:
[image]

Comment: Do you see any messages running the successful script?

Are you able to try installing the latest SSMS version? 

Can you post the scripted out command that works on the AWS system?

Comment: I updated the question with the script and messages. I'll try getting the latest SSMS to see if it works there

Comment: Same result on latest SSMS version, updated question with a screenshot of the restore dialog